# "Amendment" or "Addendum" for book correction

Tags: word-choice, british-english

A clarification of a European building code has been issued, therefore a separate correction for the book is released. What would this correction be called?

I have had the words amendment and addendum suggested from different sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Errata*** would be the term for corrections of **errors**. I think that your suggestion of ***amendment*** would be a better choice for a clarifying edit of the original document, assuming that it did not contain outright errors.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for *[corrigendum](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corrigendum)* (pluralized as *corrigenda*). Also,wiki lists *[errata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erratum)* as its synonym.Both refer to corrections made after a book has been published.

Comment: Many textbooks come out with *errata* after the book is published and corrections need to be made.

Comment: Jeff Sahol is right. *Amendment* is a better choice if the clarification is in terms of policy, etc. *Errata* is for when there are errors. Corrigendum is neutral but *Amendment* is still preferable if it fits the context. It really depends on what is meant by *clarification*.

Answer (score 1):

You indicate "a separate correction for the book is released".  A separately published section is generally a *[supplement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplement_%28publishing%29)*, "a publication that has a role secondary to that of another preceding or concurrent publication ... either by bringing it up-to-date ... or by otherwise enhancing the predecessor's coverage of a particular topic or subject matter...".

Previously-suggested *[errata or corrigenda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrigenda)* ("lists of errors and their corrections [in] form of loose, inserted sheets or bound-in pages")  and *[addenda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addendum)* ("addition required to be made to a document by its reader subsequent to its printing or publication") are specific forms of supplements, a term which is slightly more general.

*[Appendix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appendix)* typically denotes "a text added to the end of a book or an article, containing information that is important to but is not the main idea of the main text" and does not specifically connote separate publication.